# Reflection between projects based on attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have 2 projects, project A and Project B.

In project A, I have a class ClsPersoon that is decorated with the attribute Myperson.

In project B I use reflection on the exe file from project A and i want to select al types that have customAttribute MyPerson but I get an error on getCustomAttributes because this attribute is not known in project B.

How to solve this without a reference between both projects?

Comment: You can define the attribute in common project; refer common into project A and B.

Comment: No reference means no type safety. So just get all custom attributes from target and search by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to match on name, there are static methods on the Attribute class to get custom attributes on specific targets:

```
static IEnumerable<Type> TypesWithAttribute(Assembly a, string attributeName )
{
  return
    a
    .GetTypes( )
    .Where
    (
      t =>
        Attribute
        .GetCustomAttributes( t )
        .Any
        (
          att =>
          att.GetType( ).Name == attributeName
      ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: An error like that can't come from code like this. Worst case, you won't get anything back in the enumerable. Are you sure that error isn't coming from calling code? btw - case matters.

Comment: Sorry my comment was indeed wrong, Your solution works, Thanks alot!